# Unable to control SwiftUI macOS list selection styling

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

On macOS running natively (not in catalyst mode), a SwiftUI List with selection enabled has multiple style states controlled by what appear to be implicit variables that I can't seem to access. As a result, a custom `foregroundColor` on a View in a List behaves erratically. In particular, given the below example, there should *in theory* be 3 total styling states, but *in reality* there are effectively 5 possible styling states of Item 2:

| State | Foreground color | Background color | Screenshot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A. Item 2 is selected and window is active | White | Accent | [image: d] |
| B. Item 2 is selected and window is inactive | *Black ***(but should be faded blue)*** | Gray | [image: d] |
| C. Item 2 is not selected and window is active (Item 2 also looks the same for an inactive window) | Blue | None | [image: d] |
| D. Item 2 was just clicked, but we need to wait ~300ms before it becomes selected | *Blue ***(but should be white)*** | Accent | [image: d] |
| E. Item 2 was previously selected, a new item is clicked, but we need to wait ~300ms before the new item becomes selected | *Black ***(but should be blue)*** | None | [image: d] |

**How can I control the foreground color in states B, D, and E?** For cases D and E, it seems that there's some kind of built in debouncing on the macOS List selection that causes a brief delay after first clicking before actually becoming selected. Is there something like a not-debounced `isHighlighted` property? Clearly the built in system is using something like this as the non-custom list label colors immediately switch from black to white regardless of the debounce, as in Item 1 in state 5 above. For case B perhaps there's a different color property instead of `foregroundColor` that I need to use?

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Minimally reproducable example (run on macOS native, not catalyst):

```swift
@main
struct ExampleApp: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var selected: String?
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail 1"), tag: "1", selection: $selected) {
          Label("Item 1", systemImage: "tag")
        }
        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail 2"), tag: "2", selection: $selected) {
          Label {
            Text("Item 2")
              .foregroundColor(selected == "2" ? nil : .blue)
          } icon: {
            Image(systemName: "tag")
              .foregroundColor(selected == "2" ? nil : .blue)
          }
        }
      }
      .toolbar {
        Button {
        } label: {
          Image(systemName: "sidebar.left")
        }
      }
    }
    .navigationTitle("Test")
    .listStyle(.sidebar)
  }
}
```

Style state screenshots above all come from this example:

[image]

Comment: Try to move everything into dedicated root ContentView instead of making Scene updating your view states.

Comment: Good idea, but same result either way. I kept it all in the scene for the original example to keep the code more concise. I've now split it out to make it clearer.

Comment: To have full control use AppKit directly, SwiftUI does not give it for now (and probably will not do in close future).